# In VSCode intellisense is broken when using @ in import statement

Tags: visual-studio-code, es6-modules

I'm using VSCode to develop an app with VueJs, but intellisense is broken and not working if I imported modules like this:

```
import myModule from '@/path/to/myModule.js'
```

But when I import it like this the intellisense will work:

```
import myModule from './path/to/myModule.js'
```

This happens in `*.js` file or `*.vue` file.
What is the reason and is there a fix for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use `paths` in a [`jsconfig.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig) to let VS Code's tooling know how to resolve that style of paths.

At the root of your project, try creating a `jsconfig.json` with the contents:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
       "@/*": [ "root/path/to/src/*" ]
    }
  },
   "exclude": [
     "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

You can configure `@/` to resolve to whatever subdirectory you want in your workspace. Use: `"@/*": [ "./*" ]` to resolve it to root of your workspace

Comment: It worked in a clean new simple project, but in mine, for some reason, it didn't.
Do you have any idea what may cause the issue?
In my project I got only these config files (I don't if one of them may affect):
`babel.config.js, vue.config.js`